# Operand ' ==' cannot be applied to operands of type (struct)

Tags: c#, struct, equals-operator, operands

```
public class Human
{
    public setGender Gender { get; set; }

    public void setHeight(Human Person)
    {
        if (Person.Gender == setGender.Male) // <-- This is where the error is.
        {

        }
    }
}

public struct setGender
{
    public static setGender Male { get; set; }
    public static setGender Female { get; set; }
}
```

When I put in the preceding code, I get this error saying,

> operand '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Life.setGender'
>   and 'Life.setGender'

(The namespace is "Life" by the way. That is why it is 'Life.setGender')

I had tried to look it up but I still don't know what that means. Could someone please help me with error.

I am using C#.

Comment: It might help to tell us what language you're using.

Comment: Why is gender a struct anyway?

Comment: why does your struct 'gender' include 'gender' members ? I doubt that part would compile

Comment: @corn3lius The Singleton pattern uses this technique, of course it compiles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am pretty sure what you really want is this:

```
public enum Gender 
{
    Male, Female
}

public class Human
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public void setHeight(Human person)
    {
        if (person.Gender == Gender.Male)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must override the `==` operator. Check this link on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx

However I do not see what can be accomplished with this code. Enums would be appropriate to use in this case, not structs.

Comment: I know. I just answered a question regarding comparison of 2 structs. However in the given code it makes no sense.

Comment: @Cicada This answer explains why he gets an error. It is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access an instance property on the class. You may want `Person.Gender == Gender.Male` in this case.

Also note that your naming is a little off. In C# types use `PascalCase`, as do properties and methods. Fields and locals use `camelCase`.